# Syncing Audio With Video

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I am have a little problem syncing an audio track with the video,
the problem is when seeking, when the video is not buffered, the audio still play
heres my code

```
        var video_preview = document.getElementById("video-preview");
        var song_preview = document.getElementById("song");
        video_preview.onplay = function() {
            song_preview.currentTime = video_preview.currentTime;
            song_preview.play();
        };

        video_preview.onpause = function() {
           video_preview.pause();
           song_preview.pause();
        };

        video_preview.onseeking = function() {
            song_preview.currentTime = video_preview.currentTime;
            song_preview.play();
        };
```

Comment: try using preload attribute for fetching your video and then later you can sync it with your audio. Else you can try setting audio.currentTime=video.currentTime

Comment: I am already setting  audio.currentTime=video.currentTime as you can see in the code, its working on onplay perfectly, but on onseeking its not working good

Comment: does this issue persist even after the video and audio are perfectly loaded??

Comment: Yes, when the video is fully loaded and I seek the video, the audio still playing but the video sometimes stops

Comment: Have you tried pausing the audio as soon you as you start seeking - i.e. add 'song_peview.pause()' at the start of the 'video_preview.onpause' function?